# How to style u="#" in external stylesheet

Tags: css, jssor

i am trying to remove the inline css and include it into a separate stylesheet. Since it is clear to use "#" and "." for id and class, how can i externally style the "u" as in sample below. Thx in advance for any help.

```
   <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;

            background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%; height:100%;"> 
        </div> 
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;

            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Add a class for the div and, give your styles..

Comment: If you're going for complete cross browser coverage, what Raj said. Also, cannot be easier

Comment: What does `u="#"` in the question title mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
div[u=loading] { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
```

This is called the attribute selector (you can also do `*[u=...]` if you want). This won't work on earlier internet explorers (<7) or other old browsers, but will work on all modern browsers as far as I know.

Comment: Thx Los, will try this later.